# Enter Specific data depending on row criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

Afternoon,  I have the following SQL command:

SELECT        INVOICE_ID,
              ITEM_ID,
              ORDER_NO,
              CLIENT_STATE
FROM          CUSTOMER_ORDER_INV_JOIN
WHERE         ORDER_NO = '*1007';

This pulls out the following information:

[enter image description here][1]

There is a specific Criteria that I want to reach and that is the following:

On Order No: *1007, If client state on all lines = PaidPosted then I need another column to show 'PaidPosted' on all lines.
However On Order No: *1007, If Client State on 4 Lines = 'PaidPosted' but 1 or more lines = 'PostedAuth' then I need another column where all lines to show 'PostedAuth'.  However if all of the lines are NULL I need a column where all lines show 'No Invoice'.

Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output for that.

Comment: Hi, I thought I had.  What I want to see from this is only PostedAuth showing, however I want to be able to change this to PostedAuth1 for example.

Comment: *I want to be able to change this to PostedAuth1*  - what do you mean by it? It's not as clear as you might think.

Comment: @ditchy_jon85 . . . Let me second Gurv's observation.  Your description is very difficult to follow.

Comment: I am guessing that you have two tables - one for order header and another for the individual order lines.  But I shouldn't have to guess - you must make your data model explicit

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you what you need. 
You can create a Temporary Table that has your sort order:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sort_Order
(myOrder INT,
 CLIENT_STATE NVARCHAR(20)
 )

INSERT INTO #Sort_Order
VALUES(1, 'Preliminary')
INSERT INTO #Sort_Order
VALUES(2, 'PostedAuth')
INSERT INTO #Sort_Order
VALUES(3, 'PaidPosted')
```

Then you can just join it to your table and run a RANK function on it like so:

```
SELECT
A.*,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID
                   ORDER BY B.myOrder ASC) AS OrderRank
FROM #Temp A
INNER JOIN #Sort_Order B On (A.CLIENT_STATE = B.CLIENT_STATE)
WHERE A.ID = 1
```

This will give you results by RANK and you can use a WHERE statement to filter on only RANK = 1

If your data has multiple rows of the same Client State, you will need to do some kind of DISTINCT or GROUP BY.